# Sun's position on summer solstice

Tags: the-sun, declination

Let's say I am in Brasilia (latitude = 15.78°S). This is obviously south of the equator but north of the tropic of capricorn. So on the summer solstice I know that the Sun's declination is +23.26°. Does this mean that the sun will appear directly north at solar noon? Thanks.

Comment: Your location is north of the Tropic of Capricorn, not the Tropic of Cancer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Sun at solar noon (meaning that it is on the meridian) will be in one of these directions:

1. Due south if the declination of the Sun is less that your latitude. (For Brasilia, that occurs from Nov 6 to Feb 5, approximately)
2. Directly overhead (at the zenith) if the declination of the Sun is the same as your latitude. (For Brasilia, that occurs Nov 5 and Feb 6, approximately)
3. Due north if the declination of the Sun is more than your latitude. (For Brasilia, that occurs from Feb 7 to Nov 4, approximately)

Comment: Yes this is what I thought but I just wasn't very sure. Thank you very much.